# Jquery : transform nested json object to another json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

In javascript/jquery how do i achieve following

```
old_dataset = [
{
    "dob": "xyz",
    "name": {
        "first": " abc",
        "last": "lastname"
    },
    "start_date": {
        "moth": "2",
        "day": "5",
        "year": 1
    },
    "children": [
        {
            "child": {
                "id": "1",
                "desc": "first child"
            }
        },
        {
            "child": {
                "id": "2",
                "desc": "second child"
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    "dob": "er",
    "name": {
        "first": " abc",
        "last": "txt"
    },
    "start_date": {
        "moth": "2",
        "day": "5",
        "year": 1
    },
    "children": [
        {
            "child": {
                "id": "1",
                "desc": "first child"
            }
        },
        {
            "child": {
                "id": "2",
                "desc": "second child"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

]

Using jquery iterate over the above and change to following

```
new_dataset = [
{
    "dob":"xyz",
    "name": <first and last name values>
    "start_date":<value of month day year>,
    "children": [ {
       child_id :1,
       child_id : 2
      }, 
    ]
 },{
    "dob":"er",
    "name": <first and last name values>
    "start_date":<value of month day year>,
    "children": [ {
       child_id :1,
       child_id : 2
      }, 
    ]
}]
```

If someone can give the code to transform the data it would help me to understand the iteration

Comment: What's the reasoning behind `childrens` (which should be `children` I guess, at least that would be correct English) being an array with one element? I recommend to read [MDN - Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) to learn how to create and modify objects.

Comment: Just an fyi, your json syntax has some mistakes. you can use jsonlint.com to validate and correct it for you. I have done that and the correct one is http://pastebin.com/VArTyMKx

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
function transformDataset(oldDataset) {
  var newDataset = [];
  var newObj;

  for (var i = 0; i < oldDataset.length; i++) {
    newObj = transformObj(oldDataset[i]);
    newDataset.push(newObj);
  }

  return newDataset;
}

function transformObj(obj) {
  var children = obj.children;

  obj.name = obj.name.first + ' ' + obj.name.last;
  obj.start_date = obj.start_date.month + ' ' + obj.start_date.day + ' ' + obj.start_date.year;

  obj.children = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    obj.children.push(children[i].child.id);
  }

  return obj;
}

var new_dataset = transformDataset(old_dataset);
```

Note that new_dataset will have an array of *child id* instead of an object with multiple `child_id` properties.
You also had a typo in `old_dataset.start_date.month` (was written `moth`)(or maybe that was intentional).

Answer (score 0):

use map first to iterate the array data (old_dataset), replace element name & start_date with new value then return the array

```js
const old_dataset = [
{
    "dob": "xyz",
    "name": {
        "first": " abc",
        "last": "lastname"
    },
    "start_date": {
        "moth": "2",
        "day": "5",
        "year": 1
    },
    "children": [
        {
            "child": {
                "id": "1",
                "desc": "first child"
            }
        },
        {
            "child": {
                "id": "2",
                "desc": "second child"
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    "dob": "er",
    "name": {
        "first": " abc",
        "last": "txt"
    },
    "start_date": {
        "moth": "2",
        "day": "5",
        "year": 1
    },
    "children": [
        {
            "child": {
                "id": "1",
                "desc": "first child"
            }
        },
        {
            "child": {
                "id": "2",
                "desc": "second child"
            }
        }
    ]
}
]

let new_dataset = old_dataset.map((arr) => {
  arr.name = `${arr.name.first} ${arr.name.last}`
  arr.start_date = `${arr.start_date.moth} ${arr.start_date.day} ${arr.start_date.year}`
  return arr
})

console.log(new_dataset)
```